# React-select - Is there a way to load values only on typing the characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

The default behaviour of `react-select` is to load all the values from the state just on clicking over the field. But the desired field is to load the values only on typing the character(s). Is there any `api` available to achive this?

Comment: Can you provide some code? how you are using react-select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need openMenuOnClick prop: https://codesandbox.io/s/lp9yz26y4q

Code from link:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Select from "react-select";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        openMenuOnClick={false}
        options={[
          { label: "option1" },
          { label: "option2" },
          { label: "option3" }
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```